# What is the correct venue for questions about MS Expression Blend: Stack Overflow or Super User?

Tags: support

I have never used anything but Visual Studio for designing a [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) UI, but I recently began playing with Microsoft [Expression Blend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Blend), and inevitably, some questions have come up.

I noticed that there was very little on Super User about Expression Blend, and one of the two questions I did find was closed and migrated to Stack Overflow. Also, there's quite a bit more Expression Blend content on Stack Overflow (though I haven't noticed a lot of "How do you do this?" type questions).

Perhaps I've answered my own question just by citing these trends, but what I've observed goes against my understanding of the purposes of Stack Overflow and Super User. In my mind, Expression Blend is to [XAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) as [Dreamweaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver) is to HTML (both provide GUI interfaces for producing markup), yet you see plenty of Dreamweaver questions on Super User and almost no Expression Blend questions.

Which site should I use if I have a question about how to do something in Expression Blend, Super User or Stack Overflow? (Just to provide an example, I was curious how to edit the `ItemContainerStyle` of a `TabControl`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, because both Dreamweaver and Blend are programmer/designer oriented programs, it is more likely that the questions you have will be appropriate for Stack Overflow. Similarly, Visual Studio questions (even simple ones) are generally for Stack Overflow because the purposes of those programs are to work with and generate code.

I'm not as familiar with Dreamweaver, but Blend at the very least has a strong component that is related to user-generated and not computer generated code, for that reason, it is easiest to cluster the Blend related questions all together on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8):

If it relates to coding with a markup language of some sorts then it belongs on SO in my opinion.

If it's about how do you do X in program Y, it's more likely to be for SU. Not guaranteed though.

Comment: HTML would be Expression Web; Blend mainly handles xaml.... but other than that, I agree ;-p

Comment: I provided an example question. Which site would you post *that* question to?

Comment: I don't know much about Blend and XAML so I cant answer that clearly.